# Why do two identical chunks of python code take such drastically different amounts of time to complete?

Tags: python, time, struct, embedded-linux, mmap

I've got the following code:

```
from mmap import mmap
from struct import unpack
from time import time,sleep

mmap_offset     =0x44c00000
mmap_size       =0x48ffffff-mmap_offset
DCAN1           =0x481D0000-mmap_offset #DCAN1 registers TIRM 2.1
DCAN1_IF1CMD    =0x100+DCAN1

with open("/dev/mem", "r+b") as f:
    testMap=mmap(f.fileno(),mmap_size,offset=mmap_offset)


start1=time()
unpacked1=unpack("<L",testMap[DCAN1_IF1CMD:DCAN1_IF1CMD+4])[0]
end1=time()

start2=time()
unpacked2=unpack("<L",testMap[DCAN1_IF1CMD:DCAN1_IF1CMD+4])[0]
end2=time()


print end2-start2,end1-start1
```

Which repeatably(to within a few microseconds) gives me the following output:

```
3.00407409668e-05 0.0001220703125
```

I'm not sure where this is coming from and would really like to understand. Any thoughts? My version and CPU info is below.

```
Linux version 3.2.34 (koen@Angstrom-F16-vm-rpm) (gcc version 4.5.4 20120305 (pre
release) (GCC) ) #1 Wed Nov 21 14:17:11 CET 2012

Processor       : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 718.02
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x3
CPU part        : 0xc08
CPU revision    : 2

Hardware        : am335xevm
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

EDIT:
I've updated the code to rerun the chunk 10 times in the following manner:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    start2=time()
    unpacked2=unpack("<L",testMap[DCAN1_IF1CMD:DCAN1_IF1CMD+4])[0]
    end2=time()
    print end2-start2
```

Which results in:

```
9.20295715332e-05
6.103515625e-05
3.00407409668e-05
3.09944152832e-05
3.09944152832e-05
3.00407409668e-05
3.09944152832e-05
3.09944152832e-05
2.98023223877e-05
3.09944152832e-05
```

It seems to settle in at 3e-05... whether I run it 10 or a hundred times.

Comment: Maybe it's an initialization/caching issue.  Btw, I cannot reproduce this.  My output for this is `0.0014169216156 0.00145888328552`.

Comment: What happens if you execute that code more than twice?  What durations do you get for the third, fourth, fifth, and hundredth execution?

Comment: @Alfe, I've updated the code with the relevant information, it seems like it settles in around 30 us

Comment: You don't happen to use a Python version with JIT compiler (pypy e. g.)?  That would clearly explain any speedup on repetitions.  But also other aspects like caching data explain speedups.  Why is this such an issue to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely any speedup on repetitions is due to caching effects somewhere below the Python level, i. e. Python interpreter (maybe with a JIT like pypy), underlying libraries (libc, stdlib, ...), or even processor caching.